# Fatal error:Uncaught Error: call to undefined method

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3

i am getting this error only for few customers (Fatal error:Uncaught Error: call to undefined method)

For Reference please find the attached image.
[image]

Thanks
Somu N

Comment: did you check log?

Comment: No i didnt check the log

Comment: can you do that for me?

Comment: Sure Sagar Parikg SGR

Comment: Please find the link for System log file https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oX_VK8rVhpb42aUZhcuLJerAU3RdC-6L i am getting above error for only few customers.

Answer (score 0):

Add simple condition in

> Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Helper\Product\Options\Loader::load(ProductInterface
>   $product) after line no : 51

```
if (get_class($typeInstance) == 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Simple' || get_class($typeInstance) == 'Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Type')
{
            return null;
}
```